# Как сравнить время?

Tags: php

Как сравнить время в php? Нужно узнать что время введённое в форму не меньше 8:00 и не больше 20:00.

Comment: `if (strlen($s) < 5) $s = "0"+$s;
return $s>="08:00" && $s<= "20:00";` Ну или как-то так...

Comment: Что такое "s", "s.length"? и "08:00" в данном случае просто строка текста. Это вообще на каком языке?

Comment: псевдоязык это был.

Comment: Зачем мне ваш псевдоязык? Бессмыслица какая то. Я же не могу сравнивать строки. Мне надо время сравнивать, а если через объект  Date делать, то тогда ещё дату нужно прибавлять

Comment: а вы попробуйте) работать будет

Comment: Дожились , люди не ищут решения и направления а тупо просят готовый ответ =( скучно же

Comment: Боюсь, здесь даже готовый ответ может не подойти.

Comment: Да, все ответы с ошибками -  $date_min = new DateTime("8:00") интерпретируется неправильно.

Comment: "Дожились , люди не ищут решения и направления а тупо просят готовый ответ" - а другие не понимая вопроса пишут ответы.

Comment: Что у вас не правильно интерпретируется? Код рабочий.
Если дата находится в пределах от 8:00 до 20:00 включительно, то функция вернет true, иначе - ложь. Что в нем может интерпретироваться неправильно?

Comment: Код не может быть рабочий потому что не указан формат

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$start_time = new DateTime($date . $start);
$end_time = new DateTime($date . $end);
$start_time_start_limit = new DateTime($date . "08:00");
$start_time_end_limit = new DateTime($date . "20:00");
$error = '';
if ($start_time > $end_time)
    $error .= "End of time can not bіt less than the start time<br />";
if ($start_time < $start_time_start_limit)
    $error .= "Start time can not bit less 8:00<br />";
if ($start_time > $start_time_end_limit)
    $error .= "Start time can not bit more 20:00<br />";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function timeIn($time, $min, $max) {
    $time = strtotime($time);

    return strtotime($min) <= $time && $time <= strtotime($max);
}

if (timeIn($_POST['time'], '8:00', '20:00')) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Как вариант :

```
    /**
     * Получить разницу в днях между 2 дат
     * @param type $date1
     * @param type $date2
     */
    protected function dateDiff($date1, $date2)
    {
        $datetime1 = date_create($date1);
        $datetime2 = date_create($date2);
        $interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);
        return $interval->format('%a');
    }
```

По аналогии сравниваете часы

Answer (score -2):

```
<?php

    function DateCheck($date) 
    {
       $date_min = new DateTime("8:00"); // минимальное значение времени
       $date_max = new DateTime("20:00"); // максимальное значение времени
       $date_now = new DateTime($date); // текущее значение времени
       // Проверяем, находится ли $date_now в диапазоне
       if ($date_now >= $date_min && $date_now <= $date_max) 
       {
           return true;
       } 
       return false;
    }
    if (DateCheck("8:00"))
    {
        print("Все хорошо.");
    } else
    {
        print("Все плохо.");
    };
?>
```

http://ideone.com/VOOBRr

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы благодарен за ваш экспертный комментарий к приведенному выше коду.